# Can't install geopandas in Anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, geopandas

I am trying to install the `geopandas` package with Anaconda Prompt, but after I use `conda install geopandas` an unexpected thing happened:

```bash
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages
```

After this, it proceeds to search for conflicts, but hours pass without finishing. In the end, I still cannot use `geopandas`.

I have also tried installing `geopandas` in a different virtual environment and it works but I do not know how to use the environment in Jupyter Notebooks.

I would like to know, **how can install `geopandas` without a separate environment?**

Or, alternatively, **how can I use `geopandas` in Jupyter Notebooks after install it in a separate environment?**

Comment: Looks like geopandas dependencies have conflict with existing versions of installed packages. Either downgrade/update the conflict packages or create a new conda env
if you are interested in new conda environment refer here. https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084

Comment: What were the conflicts? Please share the content of your environment.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can [install geopandas with pip](https://geopandas.org/install.html#installing-with-pip), however, geopandas requires other dependencies (such as pandas, fiona, shapely, pyproj, rtree). You need to make sure that they are properly installed. After that you should be able to use them in jupyter with a simple `import geopandas`.

Comment: I could install geopandas downloaded geopandas, shapely, GDAl, fiona, etc in wheel format. Then i sued pip as you reccomend and now i can use geopandas.

Comment: @SantiagoCardonaUrrea I imagine that neither of you are aware of the particularities involved in using pip with Conda, see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.

Comment: Whatever the case, This is the correct answer. Steps I followed.
conda install geos shapely pyproj
pip install fiona
pip install geopandas

Comment: I think it is not well-behaved method to have composite installation conda/pip.
But I surely succeeded to use pip instead of conda for geopandas in my clean anaconda env which refuse to allow conda installation.  

During my try and error, I tried
- specify conda-forge, broken channel 
- one by one installation of pre-requisites like pandas, pyrpoj etc... 
- clean conda env
- clean Anaconda (reinstall)
pyproj installation halts in similar reason of entire geopandas installation with conda.
Good luck trouble shooters !

Answer (score 16):

Install it in a new env, and include `ipykernel` if you plan to use it in Jupyter:

```
conda create -n my_env geopandas ipykernel
```

Note, `nb_conda_kernels` should be installed install in your base env (i.e. where you launch Jupyter from). This enables Jupyter to automatically recognize other envs that are kernel-ready:

```
conda install -n base nb_conda_kernels
```

Comment: Why can't I just straight up `conda install geopandas` ? Can you explain?

Comment: @amnesic "reasons"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install `geopandas` in an EXISTING environment, use `conda-forge` as follows:

```
conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I installed `geos` firstly: `pip install geos`, then `conda install geopandas` and everything went through.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. As far as I understand, my mistake was to install geopandas or pyproj with pip instead of conda. When trying to fix the issue (uninstalling geopandas, pyproj) I completely crashed my env.

I **fixed** the issue by completely reinstalling anaconda and creating a new separate conda env with an older version of python (python=3.8 instead of 3.9). Then everything ran smoothly.

Comment: Beware, don't mix up venv and conda envs. I suggest to have different environments for different tasks and leave alone the `base` environment

Comment: yes thanks for the comment, conda env is correct

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when Jupyter had been installed from the default channel. For me running `conda uninstall jupter` followed by `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas` worked.

Comment: so they can't co-exist?