# Cannot install geopandas

Tags: installation, anaconda, geopandas

I am trying to instal geopandas. It goes like this:

> (base) PS C:\Users\a_e_f> conda install geopandas
> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
> Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen
> solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
> Solving environment: \
> Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
> This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
> Examining tornado:*

etc etc for more than an hour.

How I got here:

- I installed anaconda many months ago but never got around to using it. Now I need to do something with geopandas so...
- I tried to update anaconda. Got some warnings & so decided to uninstall it & do a new clean install.
- I attempted to uninstall anacondas but found the instructions unclear & missed a step. Reinstalled anaconda. geopandas wouldn't install.
- Research revealed the missing uninstall step. Did it again. Looked like it was all gone.
- Installed anaconda. Verified as here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/verify-install/#
- Tried to install geopandas. See above.

I am using Windows 10

Comment: Possible dups: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60890961/570918 https://stackoverflow.com/a/67568385/570918

Comment: Thanks merv. That helped.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not install packages into the `base` environment, create new, clean ones for your project.
2. Use `conda-forge` channel where GeoPandas team has the ability to fine tune installation process

```
conda create -n geo_env
conda activate geo_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install geopandas
```

3. if that doesn't help, use mamba to install GeoPandas.

```
conda create -n geo_env
conda activate geo_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install mamba
mamba install geopandas
```

Answer (score 0):

Following merv's hints (above) I used the approach here: [Conda install some-package hangs with (Solving environment: failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927004/conda-install-some-package-hangs-with-solving-environment-failed/67568385#67568385)

That seems to have fixed the problem.

Thanks all for your help.